# How to recover LogMiner after its tablespace had been deleted?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, logs, tablespaces

Here is my story:

I created separate table space for Log Miner,

```
create tablespace logminer_ts datafile '/path/to/logminer.dbf' size 50M AUTOEXTEND ON
```

And moved Log Miner to the created table space:

```
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR_D.SET_TABLESPACE('logminer_ts');
```

Then I wanted to repeat the whole process, so I dropped the Log Miner table space:

```
DROP TABLESPACE logminer_ts INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
```

Now I have a problem, the call to `DBMS_LOGMNR_D.SET_TABLESPACE` gives error:

> ORA-04063: package body "SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR_INTERNAL" has errors
>
> ORA-06508: PL/SQL could not find program unit being called "SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR_INTERNAL"
>
> ...

Now the log miner is failing to start, it looks like some of the data had been deleted when I dropped the table space...

My question is how can I recover from this without recover from a backup?

Can I get the missing parts from other oracle and "install" on the malfunctioning DB? (some export/import things?)

Thanks a lot!